# Get the last Item which is an object from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to get the last object from an array of the objects using following way,

```
const rowLen = previous_data.High.length;
          var temp = previous_data.High.map((object,i) => {
             if (rowLen === i + 1) {
                return object;
            }
        });
```

and then I want to fill the values in the next object so, I am doing like

temp[0].keyname .

Now while getting temp it is returning me the array of object so after 2nd I get

```
[ 0: undefined, 1: {key:value}]
```

So, I am not understanding why is it returning the array and also the previous one I want only last object .

Comment: Do you just want the last element of `previous_data.High`? All you need to do for that is (with `rowLen` as defined in your code) `previous_data.High[rowLen - 1]`

Comment: @undefined Please don't treat other users in such a disrespectful way

Comment: @undefined Thanks for the help . Actually I know map returns an  array , But somehow while debugging I did not got this So, I tried and then I asked the question.

Comment: @PatrickHund "such a disrespectful way"? What is disrespectful in that comment?  I meant to say if you read the method documentation the `.map` does what it should. The rest of the comment is just a joke.

Comment: Thanks a lot @undefined for the joke

Comment: The real joke is @PatrickHund flagged the comment. My addressee was you and he was offended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Map returns a value for each iteration of the array. If you return a value from the callback function within map, that value is returned at the respective index else undefined is returned which is what you can see

Since you want only the last value from array, you could simply use `slice`

```
var temp = previous_data.High.slice(-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because map return an array you use map when you want to alter the original array not to select an element. Do it like this.
previous_data.High[previous_data.High.length -1].
This will get you the last element.

Comment: This one's *better*, since `slice()` creates a copy of the entire array.

Comment: Yes slice is better and more cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

**[Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Nested_object_and_array_destructuring)** allows you to assign variables, swap properties, ignore properties, assign default values, access as many properties as you want.

---

### Demo

```js
let arrObj = [{
    key0: "value0",
    key1: "value1",
    key2: "value2",
    key3: "value3"
  },
    [1, 2, 3],
  {
    key4: "value4"
  }];

let [{key0:K0,key1:K1,key2:K2,key3:K3},[a, b, c],{key4:last}] = arrObj;

  console.log(last);
  console.log(c);
  console.log(K1);
```